# List of Laravel validation rules

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

Is there a master list of all available rules for Laravel request validation? I have only seen the ones shown in the docs, but there must be more than just 4-5 rules. I know I can make custom ones, which I am currently, but I would like to know all of the available ones.

Comment: Where in the documentation are you looking? [Here is a list of available rules that is much longer than 4-5 rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#available-validation-rules)

Comment: @jfadich I was apparently not looking properly. I scoured the whole page, and couldn't find that. Thank you! If you can write it as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's a lot more than 4-5 validation rules. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#available-validation-rules).

This is the current list (Laravel 9):

> [Accepted](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-accepted)
>
> [Accepted
> If](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-accepted-if)
>
> [Active URL](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-active-url)
>
> [After (Date)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-after)
>
> [After Or Equal
> (Date)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-after-or-equal)
>
> [Alpha](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-alpha)
>
> [Alpha Dash](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-alpha-dash)
>
> [Alpha
> Numeric](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-alpha-num)
>
> [Array](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-array)
>
> [Bail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-bail)
>
> [Before (Date)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-before)
>
> [Before Or Equal
> (Date)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-before-or-equal)
>
> [Between](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-between)
>
> [Boolean](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-boolean)
>
> [Confirmed](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-confirmed)
>
> [Current
> Password](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-current-password)
>
> [Date](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date)
>
> [Date
> Equals](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date-equals)
>
> [Date
> Format](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date-format)
>
> [Declined](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-declined)
>
> [Declined
> If](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-declined-if)
>
> [Different](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-different)
>
> [Digits](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-digits)
>
> [Digits
> Between](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-digits-between)
>
> [Dimensions (Image
> Files)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-dimensions)
>
> [Distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-distinct)
>
> [Doesnt Start
> With](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-doesnt-start-with)
>
> [Doesnt End
> With](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-doesnt-end-with)
>
> [Email](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-email)
>
> [Ends With](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-ends-with)
>
> [Enum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-enum)
>
> [Exclude](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude)
>
> [Exclude If](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude-if)
>
> [Exclude
> Unless](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude-unless)
>
> [Exclude
> With](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude-with)
>
> [Exclude
> Without](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exclude-without)
>
> [Exists
> (Database)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exists)
>
> [File](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-file)
>
> [Filled](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-filled)
>
> [Greater Than](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-gt)
>
> [Greater Than Or
> Equal](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-gte)
>
> [Image (File)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-image)
>
> [In](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-in)
>
> [In Array](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-in-array)
>
> [Integer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-integer)
>
> [IP Address](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-ip)
>
> [JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-json)
>
> [Less Than](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-lt)
>
> [Less Than Or Equal](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-lte)
>
> [MAC Address](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-mac)
>
> [Max](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-max)
>
> [MIME Types](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-mimetypes)
>
> [MIME Type By File
> Extension](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-mimes)
>
> [Min](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-min)
>
> [Multiple Of](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#multiple-of)
>
> [Not In](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-not-in)
>
> [Not Regex](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-not-regex)
>
> [Nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-nullable)
>
> [Numeric](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-numeric)
>
> [Password](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-password)
>
> [Present](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-present)
>
> [Prohibited](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-prohibited)
>
> [Prohibited
> If](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-prohibited-if)
>
> [Prohibited
> Unless](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-prohibited-unless)
>
> [Prohibits](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-prohibits)
>
> [Regular
> Expression](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-regex)
>
> [Required](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required)
>
> [Required
> If](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-if)
>
> [Required
> Unless](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-unless)
>
> [Required
> With](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-with)
>
> [Required With
> All](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-with-all)
>
> [Required
> Without](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-without)
>
> [Required Without
> All](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-without-all)
>
> [Required Array
> Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-array-keys)
>
> [Same](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-same)
>
> [Size](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-size)
>
> [Sometimes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-when-present)
>
> [Starts
> With](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-starts-with)
>
> [String](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-string)
>
> [Timezone](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-timezone)
>
> [Unique
> (Database)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique)
>
> [URL](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-url)
>
> [UUID](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-uuid)

Answer (score 3):

If you check the Illuminate\Validation\Validator class it has quite a few arrays toward the top with different built in validation rules.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone else will find this useful, but you can use reflection to figure out the validators:

```
$validatorClass = new ReflectionClass(Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes::class);

collect($validatorClass->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC))
  ->filter(function($method){
    return Illuminate\Support\Str::startsWith($method->name,'validate');
  })
  ->map(function($method){
    return str_replace('validate_', '', Illuminate\Support\Str::snake($method->name));
  })
  ->dd();

array:68 [
  0 => "accepted"
  1 => "active_url"
  2 => "bail"
  3 => "before"
  4 => "before_or_equal"
  5 => "after"
  6 => "after_or_equal"
  7 => "alpha"
  8 => "alpha_dash"
  9 => "alpha_num"
  10 => "array"
  11 => "between"
  12 => "boolean"
  13 => "confirmed"
  14 => "date"
  15 => "date_format"
  16 => "date_equals"
  17 => "different"
  18 => "digits"
  19 => "digits_between"
  20 => "dimensions"
  21 => "distinct"
  22 => "email"
  23 => "exists"
  24 => "unique"
  28 => "file"
  29 => "filled"
  30 => "gt"
  31 => "lt"
  32 => "gte"
  33 => "lte"
  34 => "image"
  35 => "in"
  36 => "in_array"
  37 => "integer"
  38 => "ip"
  39 => "ipv4"
  40 => "ipv6"
  41 => "json"
  42 => "max"
  43 => "mimes"
  44 => "mimetypes"
  45 => "min"
  46 => "nullable"
  47 => "not_in"
  48 => "numeric"
  49 => "present"
  50 => "regex"
  51 => "not_regex"
  52 => "required"
  53 => "required_if"
  54 => "exclude_if"
  55 => "exclude_unless"
  56 => "exclude_without"
  57 => "required_unless"
  58 => "required_with"
  59 => "required_with_all"
  60 => "required_without"
  61 => "required_without_all"
  62 => "same"
  63 => "size"
  64 => "sometimes"
  65 => "starts_with"
  66 => "ends_with"
  67 => "string"
  68 => "timezone"
  69 => "url"
  70 => "uuid"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel documentation enlists all the validators

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation